# Windows Phone 8.1 VB App PhoneApplicationService

Tags: vb.net, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone, lockscreen

I have already made an windows phone app in VB to play music.
Now i want this app to work even while lookscreen.

Searching for the answer, i only found codes like this (in C#):

```
PhoneApplicationService.Current.ApplicationIdleDetectionMode = IdleDetectionMode.Disabled;
```

PhoneApplicationService is from the namespace: Microsoft.Phone.Shell

So i tryied to import this namespace,to disable the ApplicationIdleDetectionMode , but it doesnt seem to exist.

So my question is: what i am doing wrong? if my xaml-app does not support the namespace at all, how do i work arround this problem?